# Can not apply flatMap on RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

In PySpark, for each element of an RDD, I'm trying to get an array of `Row` elements.Then I want to convert the result into a DataFrame.

I have the following code:

```
  simulation = housesDF.flatMap(lambda house: goThroughAB(jobId, house))
  print simulation.toDF().show()
```

Within that, I am calling these helper methods:

```
def simulate(jobId, house, a, b):
  return Row(jobId=jobId, house=house, a=a, b=b, myVl=[i for i in range(10)])

def goThroughAB(jobId, house):
  print "in goThroughAB"
  results = []
  for a in as:
    for b in bs:
      results += simulate(jobId, house, a, b)
  print type(results)
  return results
```

Strangely enough `print "in goThroughAB"` doesn't have any effect, as there is no output on the screen.

However, I am getting this error:

```
---> 23   print simulation.toDF().show()
     24 
     25   dfRow = sqlContext.createDataFrame(simulationResults)

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/context.py in toDF(self, schema, sampleRatio)
     62         [Row(name=u'Alice', age=1)]
     63         """
---> 64         return sqlContext.createDataFrame(self, schema, sampleRatio)
     65 
     66     RDD.toDF = toDF

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/context.py in createDataFrame(self, data, schema, samplingRatio)
    421 
    422         if isinstance(data, RDD):
--> 423             rdd, schema = self._createFromRDD(data, schema, samplingRatio)
    424         else:
    425             rdd, schema = self._createFromLocal(data, schema)

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/context.py in _createFromRDD(self, rdd, schema, samplingRatio)
    308         """
    309         if schema is None or isinstance(schema, (list, tuple)):
--> 310             struct = self._inferSchema(rdd, samplingRatio)
    311             converter = _create_converter(struct)
    312             rdd = rdd.map(converter)

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/context.py in _inferSchema(self, rdd, samplingRatio)
    261 
    262         if samplingRatio is None:
--> 263             schema = _infer_schema(first)
    264             if _has_nulltype(schema):
    265                 for row in rdd.take(100)[1:]:

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py in _infer_schema(row)
    829 
    830     else:
--> 831         raise TypeError("Can not infer schema for type: %s" % type(row))
    832 
    833     fields = [StructField(k, _infer_type(v), True) for k, v in items]

TypeError: Can not infer schema for type: <type 'str'>
```

On this line:

```
  print simulation.toDF().show()
```

So it looks like `goThroughAB` is not executed, which means the `flatMap` may not be executed.

What is the issue with the code?

Comment: Print statements are useless in distributed environment. And this question as well without example `housesDF.`.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are not printing on the driver but on Spark executors. As you know, the executors are remote processes which execute Spark tasks in parallel. They do print that line but on their own console. You don't know which executor runs a certain partition and you should never rely on print statements in a distributed environment.

Then the problem is that when you want to create the DataFrame, Spark needs to know the schema for the table. If you don't specify it, it will use the sampling ratio and will check some rows in order to determine their types. If you do not specify the sampling ratio, it will only check the first row. This happens in your case and you probably have a field for which the type cannot be determined (it is probably null).

To solve this, you should either add the schema to the toDF() method or specify a non zero sampling ratio. The schema could be created in advance like this:

```
schema = StructType([StructField("int_field", IntegerType()),
                     StructField("string_field", StringType())])
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is not correct. `results += simulate(jobId, house, a, b)` would try to concatenate row and fail. If you don't see `TypeError`  it is not reached and your code fails somewhere else, probably when you create `housesDF`.

Answer (score -1):

The key issue, as pointed out by others, is `results += simulate(jobId, house, a, b)` which won't work when `simulation` returns a Row object. You could try to make `results` a `list` then use `list.append`. But why not `yield`?

```
def goThroughAB(jobId, house):
  print "in goThroughAB"
  results = []
  for a in as:
    for b in bs:
      yield simulate(jobId, house, a, b)
```

What happened when you `+` two Row objects?

```
In[9]:
from pyspark.sql.types import Row
Row(a='a', b=1) + Row(a='b', b=2)

Out[9]:
('a', 1, 'b', 2)
```

Then `toDF` sampled the first element and found it a `str` (your jobId), hence the complain

```
TypeError: Can not infer schema for type: <type 'str'>
```